# javascript sql builder with quotes handle

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I am building my sql queries with [squel](http://hiddentao.github.io/squel/), a lightweight library for building sql queries. Here is an example:

```
var s = squel.insert();
s.into("events");
s.set("admin_id", adminId);
s.set("start_date", startDate);
s.set("end_date", endDate);
s.set("group_id", groupId);
s.set("title", title);
s.set("location_id", locationId);
s.set("location_name", locationName);
```

The problem is that squel doesn't support entries with quotes. (i.e. for example, setting a value for a field to *"O'Brien"*).

Can anyone recommend a javascript library that supports this?

Comment: Can't you just encode any string values before adding them? Double up all the single quotes.

Comment: @RhysJones tried this, but the library seems to remove the doubled quotes

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru [Looks fine](http://jsfiddle.net/j1e11tdw/) to me.

Comment: @RhysJones that's weird, i'll check again. certainly didn't work for me.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to not use Squel for any SQL stuff. It's not only insecure as it doesn't bother escaping or quoting, it's also the slowest SQL builder I have encountered. Here is a simple benchmark that I wrote to tune my own project:

https://github.com/jsstuff/xql-bench

And according to results Squel is like an order of magnitude slower than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very surprised that SQUEL doesn't handle this because string delimiters in strings is a pretty common occurrence, but, how about using [DONTQUOTE](http://hiddentao.github.io/squel/api.html#insert_set) and handling the quoting yourself where necessary?

```
s.set("location_name", locationName, { dontQuote: true });
```